# Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream. used a security protocol `Tls12`, `Tls11`, `Tls`, and `Ssl3`

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, networking, tcp, payment-gateway

**Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.** 
but I also used a security protocol  `Tls12`, `Tls11`, `Tls`, and `Ssl3` but not solve this problem.[image]

Comment: Please post the **code** that's causing the issue, not a screenshot.  You are at risk of this being closed.

Comment: ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 |
                                 SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
                                 SecurityProtocolType.Tls |                                 
                                 SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
           HttpWebRequest webRequest = PayeezyDevSDK.Create_Request(url, timestamp, nonce, token, apiKey, authorization, jsonString);
         
           StreamWriter writer = null;
           writer = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());